# ¿Configurar .htacces para acceder a un archivo?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony3

Tengo un proyecto de symfony en mi directorio raíz, y tengo las siguientes líneas en mi .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mipagina.mx$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mipagina.mx$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1
</IfModule>
```

Con esto mi página va bien, pero ahora que quiero tener mi archivo `robots.txt` en la raíz, como lo indica Google este no se puede acceder.

Si coloco `www.mipagina.mx/robots.txt` me aparece un mensaje de 404 not found, ya que el framework de symfony lo toma como un controlador.

¿Cómo podría configurar el .htaccess para que no lo tome como parte del proyecto sino que es un archivo que está en el servidor?

Answer (score 1):

Poniendo una regla específica para `robots.txt` que haga que no se evalúen más reglas:

```py
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Si accede a robots.txt, que no procese nada más
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ - [L]

# Y de paso uno tus dos condiciones en una ;-)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?mipagina\.mx$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) web/$1
```

- El `-` le dice que no reescriba nada.
- El [`[L]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) ([*last*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)) le dice que no siga procesando más reglas.